# Sending and receiving "raw" Apple Events from JavaScript on OS X (El Capitan)

Tags: javascript, applescript, osx-elcapitan, javascript-automation

I am trying to make use of the new [JavaScript Automation feature](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/Introduction.html) in OS X (10.11) to script an application that does not offer a dictionary. I have an AppleScript that interacts with  that application using raw Apple Events, like so:

```
tell application "Bookends"
  return «event ToySSQLS» "authors REGEX 'Johnson' "
end tell
```

Now my question is: how do I translate this to JavaScript? I cannot find any information on the Javascript OSA API to send and receive raw Apple events.

One possible workaround might be to [call a piece of AppleScript through the shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28638409/how-to-translate-this-slider-value-change-from-applescript-to-javascript?rq=1), but I would prefer to work with a "real" API.

Answer (score 1):

You can at least do something faster than a shell script call by using OSAKit in a couple of helper functions:

```
// evalOSA :: String -> String -> IO String
function evalOSA(strLang, strCode) {

    var oScript = ($.OSAScript || (
            ObjC.import('OSAKit'),
            $.OSAScript))
        .alloc.initWithSourceLanguage(
            strCode, $.OSALanguage.languageForName(strLang)
        ),
        error = $(),
        blnCompiled = oScript.compileAndReturnError(error),
        oDesc = blnCompiled ? (
            oScript.executeAndReturnError(error)
        ) : undefined;

    return oDesc ? (
        oDesc.stringValue.js
    ) : error.js.NSLocalizedDescription.js;
}

// eventCode :: String -> String
function eventCode(strCode) {
    return 'tell application "Bookends" to «event ToyS' +
        strCode + '»';
}
```

which then allow you to write functions like:

```
// sqlMatchIDs :: String -> [String]
function sqlMatchIDs(strClause) {
    // SELECT clause without the leading SELECT keyword
    var strResult = evalOSA(
        '', eventCode('SQLS') +
        ' "' + strClause + '"'
    );

    return strResult.indexOf('\r') !== -1 ? (
        strResult.split('\r')
    ) : (strResult ? [strResult] : []);
}
```

and calls like

```
sqlMatchIDs("authors like '%Harrington%'")
```

Fuller set of examples here: [JavaScript wrappers for Bookends functions](https://www.sonnysoftware.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=4017)